# How to resolve technical debts in sonaQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, technical-debt

I've technical debt for my java project i need to resolve them in sonarQube. can somebody guide me how to solve those technical debts.

Comment: I'm sure someone who has seen these technical debt items can guide you.  Sadly, given the current form of this question, that won't be any of us.

Comment: IMO, this question should not have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will not be your preferred answer, but best way to reduce the technical dept in Sonar will be to resolve the issues.

Another possibility would be to exclude some packages from the analysis itself, but then you will not have any metrics like code-coverage or something else.

The third possibility is to change some rules to be more liberally.

But the second and third possibility will not really reduce the technical dept they will only "fit the view" of it.